# Excel convert data to string

Tags: excel, vba

i'm learning how to create a Macro in EXCEL VBA, and I want to convert a data, for example **July-2019** which is located in a certain cell, into a two cells, first cell **2019**, second cell **July**.

Comment: Look up the `Split()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below assuming that your date is in A1 :

```
Sub test()


    Range("B1").Value = Day(CDate(Range("A1")))
    Range("C1").Value = Month(CDate(Range("A1")))
    Range("D1").Value = Year(CDate(Range("A1")))


End Sub
```

**BEFORE**
  :
[image]

**OUTPUT AFTER :**[image]

**EDIT**

```
Sub test()

Dim DateDay As String
Dim DateMonth As string
Dim DateYear As String

DateDay = Day(CDate(Range("A1")))
DateMonth = Month(CDate(Range("A1")))
DateYear = Year(CDate(Range("A1")))


End Sub
```

Comment: How can I put each output in a variable? 
i want to put the day in - Dim day as String

Answer (score 0):

An example in VBA that does this would be the following (Assumption: the original date is in cell A1):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, "-")(1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, "-")(0)
```

What this does is it splits the initial date ("July-2019") into different strings spearated by the delimiter (in this case "-"). If you need to do this for an entire column of dates you will need to wrap this in a For- or While-Loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Code below, the Variable will be an Array containing the 2 strings.

```
StringtoSplit = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

SeperatedValuesArray = Split(StringtoSplit, "-")
```